# Godot clean output log defaults

Tags: godot

Whenever output gets cleared on restart, it first gets padded with

```
--- Debugging process started ---
Godot Engine v3.2...
OpenGL ES 3.0...
 
Registered camera...
```

(truncated, actually more info)

How to get rid of it? I don't mind `Debugging process started` but everything else gotta go.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two output lines are hardcoded and can't be removed without recompiling the engine from source. (To remove those from an exported project, you'll have to recompile the export templates instead.)

`--- Debugging process started ---` is printed by the editor, not the Godot binary itself when starting up.

Comment: Disappointing but thank you. Any way to clear output programatically instead, to emulate a clear output log?

Comment: If you're running Godot using an external process, you could place its output into a pipe or buffer then handle it that way. This is commonly done for filtering a program's output.

Also, why do you need to have a clean output? Are you using Godot's standard output as an input for another program or something along those lines?

Comment: Using just for simple debugging before setting up properly. So no special reason besides cleanliness. Thank you for your responses. I'll be looking into sending output to editor (vscode). Cheers